# Persistence strategies for High Replication environment (Google App Engine)

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have this code thtat works just fine w/o HR:

```
protected Entity createEntity(Key key, Map<String, Object> props){
    Entity result = null;
    try {
        Entity e = new Entity(key);
        Iterator it = props.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = (Map.Entry<String, Object>) it.next();
            String propName = entry.getKey();
            Object propValue = entry.getValue(); 
            setProperty(e, propName, propValue);
        }
        key = _ds.put(e);
        if (key != null)
            result = _ds.get(key);
    } catch (EntityNotFoundException e1) {
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is just a simple method where its function is to create a new `Entity` out a a given `key`, just return NULL otherwise. This works fine without the HR configuration in JUnit however when I configured it, I am always getting an error, where `_ds.get(key)` can't find the key throwing:

```
EntityNotFoundException: No entity was found matching the key:
```

Specifically when doing:

```
while(it.hasNext()){
   // stuff
   createEntity(key, map); 
   // stuff
}
```

I assume that the problem in my code is that it tries to fetch the entity too soon. If thats is the case, how can I deal with this wihout resorting to `Memcache` or anything like that.

**Update:**

When the `createEntity` is executed within a transaction, it fails. However if I remove it outside of the transaction if fails miserably.  I need to be able to run within a transaction, since my higher level API put lots of objects that needs to be there as a group.

**Update:**

I followed Strom's advise however I found a weird side effect, not doing a `_ds.get(key)` on the method, makes my `PreparedQuery` `countEntities` to fail. Where if add a `_ds.get(key)` even I don't do anything or save the `Entity` return from that get `countEntities` return the expected count. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to create a new entity and then read back that entity within the same transaction? Can't be done.

Queries and gets inside transactions see a single, consistent snapshot of the datastore that lasts for the duration of the transaction. [1](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/transaction_isolation)

In a transaction, all reads reflect the current, consistent state of the Datastore at the time the transaction started. This does not include previous puts and deletes inside the transaction. Queries and gets inside a transaction are guaranteed to see a single, consistent snapshot of the Datastore as of the beginning of the transaction. [2](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions#Isolation_and_Consistency)

This consistent snapshot view also extends to reads after writes inside transactions. Unlike with most databases, queries and gets inside a Datastore transaction do not see the results of previous writes inside that transaction. Specifically, if an entity is modified or deleted within a transaction, a query or get returns the original version of the entity as of the beginning of the transaction, or nothing if the entity did not exist then. [2](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions#Isolation_and_Consistency)

PS. Your assumption is worng, it's impossible to fetch an entity by key "too soon". Fetches by key are strongly consistent.

Also, why do you need to retrieve the entity again anyway? You just put it in the datastore yourself, so you already have its contents.

So change this part:

```
key = _ds.put(e);
    if (key != null)
        result = _ds.get(key);
```

To this:

```
key = _ds.put(e);
    if (key != null)
        result = e; // key.equals(e.getKey()) == true
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked that it had a weird side-effect on my app

Answer (score 0):

Welcome in GAE environment, try to read it more times before you give up :

```
 int counter = 0;
 while (counter < NUMBER_OF_TRIES){
  try {

   //calling storage or any other non-reliable thing
   if(success) {break;} //escape away if success

   } catch(EntityNotFoundException e){
     //log exception
     counter++;
   }
 }
```

Important note from google documentation : **"the rate at which you can write to the same entity group is limited to 1 write to the entity group per second."**

source : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore

Comment: This is for doing datastore put,  but does it also apply with put then get?

Comment: I'm wondering for 1 sec, what could be the best value of NUMBER_OF_TRIES

Comment: Here's what I get when doing this: IllegalStateException: Transaction is in state COMMITTED.  There is no legal transition out of this state.

Comment: this is for get operation and number_of_tries should be e.g. 3 don`t put there some huge values to get 1 second of time - that`s not my intetion.