# Entity count does not update until entity fetch

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I found something rather weird with my GAE Datastore experiments. I am using GAE SDK 1.7.5. 
And I am not sure if my finding is correct.

Basically, I found out that putting entities into the Datastore and doing a count does not return the correct value, until a Datastore get is execute.

If you want to dig deeper here is the actual codes from my previous SO question:

[Persistence strategies for High Replication environment (Google App Engine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922277/persistence-strategies-for-high-replication-environment-google-app-engine)

Also I tried this with a similar library: https://github.com/koher/Koherent-App-Engine-Library-for-Java

And I am experiencing the same findings. Can anyone help clarify me on this issue I see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have encountered the eventual consistency property of the HRD.

Count uses indexes to get the result. After a new entity is saved, indexes are built asynchronously, which result in the fact that `get` after `put` will always return the result (strong consistency), but `query` after `put` is not guaranteed to to return result immediately (eventual consistency).

The docs are a bit vague on this subject, but it does mention that `get` after `put` forces the "apply" phase, probably resulting in indexes being applied too: see point 1. in section "The Return Value" of the [Life Of The Datastore Write](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/life_of_write).

So `put` and then `query` is not guaranteed to give you the expected result, but `put`, `get` and `query` is ( at least that's how I read the docs). That would explain your findings.

Comment: get after put forces the "apply" --> this seems to answer my question, so when the app call for get, the queries will likely to get the actual value as what I am experiencing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're getting this result on the local development server with eventual consistency enabled?

You're not getting the correct count due to the eventual consistency behavior of the datastore.  That's the way it is.

On the development server, a consistent operation like a get() will cause the subsequent queries to show the consistent results.  This isn't quite the same behavior as the production servers.